# How to add text into the main canvas with FLOT but outside the graph

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm facing a little problem here.

I need to add text inside the canvas but under X axis of the graph.

In fact if someone would know how to extend the space of the canvas to add stuff under the graph and add text there, it would be perfect.

[image]

The image is actually a canvas saved with POST ajax by transmitting base64 representation of the canvas.

Actually the legend is now inside the canvas and is not HTML text anymore.

I need it to be inside the canvas of the graph, but under the graph.

Is it clear enough?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is the following.

I created one canvas in the memory and added the legend inside by reading the information inside the HTML legend with a loop.

Then I created a third canvas that contains the drawing of the graph canvas, and the drawing of the legend canvas.

After that, I send the information through AJAX to the server and save it as PNG.

Here's the PNG result:
[image]

So people saying we cannot export a Flot graph are wrong.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the flot documentation on Hooks:

https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#hooks

It sounds like the `drawBackground` hook might work for you. It will let you draw on the canvas before Flot draws the rest of the graph.

Comment: I'll try it out, and give news after. If it works, I will accept the answer. Thank you.